# Not possible to print GeoServer layers with CQL filters

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, geoexplorer, mapfish, cql

I use geoexplorer together with GeoServer and mapfish. 
I make a WMS request passing in it two layers with corresponding CQL filters. I make this request through Geoexplorer to GeoServer.
This works normally if the CQL filters are different to each other. But if apply the same CQL filter to both layers then its not possible the layers to get printed (on mapfish).

For example if I have the following CQL filter for both layers:

```
iso3=NGA
```

the layers won't even printed on the mapfish output (the pdf).

If my CQL filter for one layer is:

```
iso3=NGA
```

and for the other

```
iso3=COD
```

then it will work and the layers will be printed correctly in the pdf.

When I check the geoserver log I see the following error:

> org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Layers and filters are mismatched, you need to provide one filter for each layer
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.getFilter(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:507)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:362)

For some reason geoserver or geoexplorer or mapfish is merging the filters, which are identical. Or at least I assume that.

Does anyone has any idea what's going on?

Comment: This must be related: http://git.net/ml/general/2014-02/msg24212.html